# Assigning value to a specific input where input name isn't unique

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm kinda new to js/php programming and have to jump into someone elses code. :/

I have a page with 2 different divs that contains each a table:

```
<div location="A"...><table location="A"...><input type="text" id="SomeID"...>
<div location="B"...><table location="B"...><input type="text" id="SomeID"...>
```

On a click of a btn, it uses Ajax to get values to populate these fields. Once I have the values, the following code updates the input box

```
$('#SomeID').val('Obtained value').trigger('change');
```

All this works kinda ok except for one thing... How can I specify which $('#SomeID') to update (the one from location A or location B)?

Comment: by using different ids

Comment: What about the input attribute `name`? Are those unique? `$('input["SomeName"]').val('Obtained value').trigger('change');`

Comment: No, they are created dynamically so they have both the same names AND IDs

Comment: Found it :) :  $('.table-cours[location='+location_Var+'] #SomeID').val('Some Text').trigger('change');    ("table-cours" being a TABLE class name)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of location, you can use :

`$('#SomeID').attr('location').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector:

```
$('div[location="A"]').val('Obtained value').trigger('change');//for location A
```

and

```
$('div[location="A"]').val('Obtained value').trigger('change');//for location B
```

Please update your question if you didn't mean to ask this so that it can be more clear.

*I hope it helps*